# Issues displaying image on ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I am having difficulty displaying image stored in Parse.

I have created a profile creation page where users fills out a variety of information that gets recorded into parse. In this activity page a list of information from parse will be retrieved like Age, Name, Headline, and picture of many users in list (excluding current user). I have, however, experienced issues in retrieving images.With support, I have referred to it in the code, and there doesn't seem to be any visible error in the code. The only warning I get is the following:

```
The method done(ParseObject, ParseException) from the type new FindCallback<ParseUser>(){} is never used locally
```

for the line below

```
 public void done(ParseObject object,ParseException e) {
```

ImageView added in layout, and refereed to in code, but is not being displayed.
Below is the activity class
    public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

```
    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ArrayList<Images> alProfilePicture;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);


        return view;
    }

private void setConversationsList() {
    currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    alProfilePicture = new ArrayList<Images>(); 

    // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

    //  query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
    // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
    query.setLimit(1);
    query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
    //query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
    //query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
    query.orderByDescending("Name");




    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object,ParseException e) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
          public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (object != null) {

                ParseFile file = (ParseFile)object.get("Profile_Picture");
                file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {


                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {

                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                        //use this bitmap as you want
                        ImageView profileimage =(ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profilePictureresult);
                        // Set the Bitmap into the
                        // ImageView
                        profileimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    } else {
                      // something went wrong
                    }
                  }
                });

            } else {
              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();

            }
          }
        });
        }
        public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("Name").toString());








                    //       names.add(userList.get(i).getParseObject("ProfilePicture").;


                }




                usersListView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistname);
                namesArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                        openConversation(names, i);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error loading user list",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error finding that user",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Below is the XML layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bac_blue"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/userlistname"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:divider="@null"

        >

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/userlistheadline"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userlistname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:divider="@null"

        >

    </ListView>

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePictureresult"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userlistheadline"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border_image"
        android:alpha="1" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/userlistage"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profilePictureresult"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:divider="@null"

        >

    </ListView>

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/userlistactivityname"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profilePictureresult"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:divider="@null"

        >

    </ListView>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userlistactivityname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:text="Confirm" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:src="@drawable/left_right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/userlistview"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="119dp"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:src="@drawable/left_arrow2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Update

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {

```
    public void done(ParseObject object,ParseException e) {
        Log.d(Constants.LOG, "pardeobject");

    ParseFile image = object.getParseFile("ProfilePicture");


    ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profilePictureResult);

     // The placeholder will be used before and during the fetch, to be replaced by the fetched image
     // data.
     imageView.setPlaceholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_pict));
     imageView.setParseFile(image);
     imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
       @Override
       public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
         Log.i("ParseImageView",
             "Fetched! Data length: " + data.length + ", or exception: " + e.getMessage());
       }
     });
    }
```

Comment: are you sure a user is being retrieved?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. User is my class name, and ProfilePicture is my column name. There are data in the class and in the column so the list is definitely not empty. I put multiple log message, and I notice that it skips this section  public void done(ParseObject object,ParseException e) {

Comment: do you realize you have that method in your code twice?   The queries return ParseObjects - in the done methods, add some if statements and log statements to see if the query is returning an object or null

Comment: thanks for your response, but if i remove that line i recieve an error

Comment: I have decided to use ParseImageView instead based around this tutorial parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseImageView.html, but still cant managed to get it displayed. I have added an update in my initial post under the update section